# Firefox 4 Required input form RED border/outline

Tags: html, css, firefox, webforms, jquery-plugins

I have recently developed an HTML5 jQuery plugin and I'm having trouble removing the red border on required fields in FF4 beta.

I noticed that FF applies this border/outline in required fields and removes it when value is set. The problem is that I am using the value attribute to emulate the placeholder attr in older browsers. Therefore I need all inputs with this feature to not show the red line.

You can see the problem in the demo page of the [plugin here](http://www.matiasmancini.com.ar/demo_html5form_en.php)

Answer (score 111):

There's some new pseudo selectors for some of the new HTML5 form features available to you in CSS. You're probably looking for `:invalid`. The following are all from the [MDC Firefox 4 docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/4#CSS):

- The `:invalid` CSS pseudo-class is applied automatically to  elements whose contents fail to validate according to the input's type setting
- The `:-moz-submit-invalid` pseudo-class is
  applied to the submit button on form
  fields when one or more form fields
  doesn't validate.
- The `:required`
  pseudo-class is now automatically
  applied to  fields that
  specify the required attribute; the
  `:optional` pseudo-class is applied to
  all other fields.
- The
  `:-moz-placeholder` pseudo-class has
  been added, to let you style
  placeholder text in form fields.
- The `:-moz-focusring` pseudo-selector
  lets you specify the appearance of an
  element when Gecko believes the
  element should have a focus
  indication rendered.

Comment: i set up the -moz-mox-shadow property to 'none'.

Comment: You should really check his answer as "the answer", and give him an up arrow, that's how this site works.  Doing that would be a big thanks :D

Comment: There's also the `:-moz-ui-invalid` pseudo-class, which applies in a subset of cases for `:invalid`. Gecko uses it and applies a red glow using the `box-shadow` property

Answer (score 83):

To be more specific you need to apply that style to the input control.

```
input:invalid {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Scratch that. Simply `box-shadow:none` worked for me now. Sorry for the incompetence.

Comment: Add textarea also.

input:invalid,
textarea:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

Answer (score 49):

use this code as Quick and simple solution

```
:invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

:-moz-submit-invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

:-moz-ui-invalid {
  box-shadow:none;
}
```

Reference:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid

Comment: This worked perfectly for me to remove (never show) the red border around input fields when invalid in Firefox. Thanks!

Comment: The third element is what removed the red box for me.

Comment: @Andrew Swift use all of them for compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

**$("form").attr("novalidate",true);**

for your form in your global .js file or in header section.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your required `input` into a `form` with `novalidate` attribute

```
<form novalidate>
    <input required>
</form>
```