# JQuery Ajax Done with required textarea

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, textarea, required

everyone. I have a (set of) form(s) with a textarea inside. This textarea has property `required`. It works as expected. If the user tries to submit the form without filling the textarea, the browser hightlights it and notify the user.

My problem is that I intercepted form submitting with JQuery AJAX, so I can notify the user without reloading the page. The code is the following:

```
$(function () {
$('form').each(function (id, el) {
    $(el).submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var _data = $(el).serialize();
        alert(_data);
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $(el).attr('action'),
                data: _data
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            $("#notify-modal").find('.modal-body').removeClass('alert-danger');
            $("#notify-modal").find('.modal-body').addClass('alert-success');
            $("#notify-modal").find('.modal-body').text('Já recebemos sua história! Obrigado por compartilhá-la conosco!');
            $("#notify-modal").modal('show');
            $(el).find('textarea').val('');
        })
        .fail(function(data) {
            $("#notify-modal").find('.modal-body').removeClass('alert-success');
            $("#notify-modal").find('.modal-body').addClass('alert-danger');
            $("#notify-modal").find('.modal-body').text("Erro ao enviar história! Contate os administradores do site! " + data.responseText);
            $("#notify-modal").modal('show');
        });
    });
});
```

});

When the user submits a valid information, the AJAX function works as expected posting to my PHP script and displaying the modal that informs the user. But note that in `.done()` function there's a statement that clears the textarea after the data is submited (`$(el).find('textarea').val('');`). My issue is that when I clear the textarea it gets highlighted, even if the data was properly submitted, as if had been cleared **before** submiting. How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: When you say highlighted, do you mean it is focused? If so you can set the focus to whichever element you desire with jQuery's .focus() method.

Comment: In Firefox it not only gets focused. It would be no problem to me. But the textarea also gets a red glow, denoting "something is wrong". You can see it here: http://imgur.com/gallery/nO4ed
My notifying modal appeared, but also the textarea was highlighted.

Comment: Ahh, I see. That is because it is required, regardless of whether or not the user has submitted anything. Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939341/firefox-4-is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-red-border-in-a-required-form-input) for how to proceed.

Another option though would be to set the value of the text area to a space `' '` instead of nothing `''`.

Comment: @JoeLissner Your `' '` solution seems to be a good one, although a little gambiarra (kludge). Anyway, about your statement, `it is required, regardless of whether or not the user has submitted anything`, note that the second form in the image is not glowing, as no data has been submitted.

Comment: Right, but the second form hasn't been interacted with either. It will flag as an error only if a value was there, and then removed. If a value was never there, then it would only flag if the user tried to submit the form through a form submit button or input where the default event was not prevented.

Comment: Please, submit a answer so I can vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because it is required, regardless of whether or not the user has submitted anything. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939341/firefox-4-is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-red-border-in-a-required-form-input) for how to proceed. Another option though would be to set the value of the text area to a space `' '` instead of nothing `''`.

[Image of error provided by Mateus Felipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvrxj.jpg)

The second form hasn't been interacted with, which is why it is not showing an error. It will flag as an error only if a value was there, and then removed. If a value was never there, then it would only flag if the user tried to submit the form through a form submit button or input where the default event was not prevented.