# What CSS selector affects border of not filled required input?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to create a form that only uses inputs/textarea w/ border-bottom, but when left empty when using required in my syntax it gives an ugly red border around all four sides of the inputs/textarea.

```css
input, textarea {
   background-color: inherit;
   border: 0;
   border-bottom: 2px solid $primary-color;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   line-height: 2.5;
   margin-right: 25px;
   width: 25%;
}

input:last-child {
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-left: 25px;
}

input::placeholder, textarea::placeholder {
   color: #fff;
}

textarea {
   font-family: $font-family-sans-serif;
   margin: 30px 25px;
   resize: none;
   width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
<textarea name="message" cols"30" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
```

I've tried selectors like :empty / :invalid / :required
Empty doesn't seem to work. Invalid doesn't seem to work. I realized required selects all required fields and does that styling so, obviously that won't work.

What CSS selector am I looking for?

Example of what I'm referring to: 
[Red Box, What selector to target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nakpS.png)

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895141/required-input-field-gets-border-when-value-is-empty-and-color-is-styled)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Required input field gets border when value is empty and color is styled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895141/required-input-field-gets-border-when-value-is-empty-and-color-is-styled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're using firefox, which has a default red box-shadow for invalid elements.

You can get rid of it by applying

```
input:required:invalid, input:focus:invalid {
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
```

Full example bellow, be careful there, I've replaced your variables for static values

```css
input:required:invalid, input:focus:invalid {
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}

input, textarea {
   background-color: inherit;
   border: 0;
   border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
   color: black;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   line-height: 2.5;
   margin-right: 25px;
   width: 25%;
}

input:last-child {
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-left: 25px;
}

input::placeholder, textarea::placeholder {
   color: grey;
}

textarea {
   font-family: sans-serif;
   margin: 30px 25px;
   resize: none;
   width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
<textarea name="message" cols"30" rows="5" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
```