# Firefox draws red border on required select box

Tags: html, validation, angularjs

Firefox 21 draws red borders around required select-boxes when they are bound to an angularjs-model.

```
<select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.text for c in colors" required>
   <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to let Firefox validate the input **after** selecting (or not selecting) an item?

[→ A fiddle to demonstrate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/xLmC2/2/)

Comment: In your fiddle there is no "required" input element...

Comment: Sorry, Dan. I had the wrong link. Please try again. Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get around this, you can disable the required style for when the form is pristine only:

```
.ng-pristine .ng-invalid-required {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

After a user has entered invalid data (and the ng-pristine class has changed to ng-dirty), the `box-shadow` will show again b/c this rule will no longer apply.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.ng-pristine.ng-invalid-required` (no space between) as to apply it to a single element and not a parent/child structure?

Comment: Per my above comment, see liqian's answer. I hadn't noticed it before commenting.

Comment: I've filed a bug on this as this workaround only applies to Angular (as per question): https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1399046

Answer (score 7):

This has actually nothing to do with AngularJS but is a browser feature which you can control with CSS.

Take a look at this MDN-Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid and this question: [Firefox 4 Required input form RED border/outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809146/firefox-4-required-input-form-red-border-outline)

With this CSS, Firefox seems to behave the same as Chrome:

```
select:invalid {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xLmC2/6/

Comment: That's good news. But I'd actually like Firefox to validate the input. But to mee it doesn't seem to make sense if Firefox paints the border red, **before** the user has selected anything. And the question remains if the Firefox can be taught to validate the select field only **after** a user action...

Comment: seemed to be a weird bug with angularjs. FF validates after an input field is blurred. The angular validator seemed to hit every field in the form so that FF thought the user klicked through them. Still no solution. We used a workaround.

Comment: Yes this bug has nothing to do with Angular. Actually Angular/Redux-Forms gives you the tools to fix this bug quite easily using pristine classes. Unfortunately disabling box-shadow on :invalid is not a great solution.

Answer (score 2):

@klamping: Your solution kinda works, but: As soon as you start typing in *another* field, your field gets the red shadow (since `form.ng-pristine` is not there anymore).

Better way:

```
.ng-untouched.ng-invalid-required { box-shadow:none; }
```

Drawback: The red shadow isn't shown when the user submits the form without ever clicking into this field (but the popup-tooltip *is* shown).

@DanEEStar: The problem only occurs if AngularJS *is* present. Your solution certainly works, but breaks the red highlighting completely (i.e. after form submission too).

I've created a bug report for AngularJS here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12102

Example:

```
<div ng-app>
<form>
<input type="text" ng-model="a" required>
</form>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5yh58orm/11/

Answer (score 2):

Thomas Landauer's solution kinda works :), but as soon as you click/focus the field, the field shadow turn to be red again,

I suggest to use:

```
.ng-pristine.ng-invalid-required { box-shadow:none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

For angular2, this is:

```
.ng-pristine.ng-invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To completly remove it type in css:

```
:-moz-ui-invalid:not(output) {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I used a select box outside of a form. The problem was fixed when I did this:

```
<form novalidate>
    <select>
    <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I think then that this is a browser thing and nothing to do with angular?